# Where are my Fonts?

Tags: macos, font

I'm on Big Sur 11.2.2

My Font Book shows a family of Chinese fonts:[image: FontBook]

Pages is able to use this font:

[image: PagesOk]

I want to add this font to ImageMagick, but I can't find it anywhere.
I was able to find fonts in only two locations - one is
Macintosh HD/System/Library/Fonts  -- which contains *most* (but not all!) the fonts I see in Font Book. The other is Macintosh HD/Library - which contains just one symbolic link to a font
living in Macintosh HD/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental - (which does *not* contain the font I am looking for).
Moreover, the folder /Users/'user_name'/Library/Fonts  is empty.

So the question is obviously: Where is the Kaiti SC font?

Comment: I think there a "show in finder" option if you right click on the font

Comment: @MohitGarg There is, but it's disabled for downloadable fonts.

Comment: Maybe this Apple support document  [Change Font Book preferences on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/font-book/change-font-book-preferences-fntbk1004/mac) contain helpful information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kai TC is a "Downloadable Font Asset" -- Apple parlance for an optional extra. Its Location should be shown in Font Book's Info panel.

Select the font, and click on the ***i*** icon in the tool bar.

Also, right-click on the font for a "Reveal in Finder" menu item.

If memory serves, these fonts go somewhere under `/System/Library/Assets`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The info icon is silent about the location. The "Show in Finder" is disabled; However, /System/Library/AssetsV2 contains the sneaky font. Thanks!