# MacOS Ventura: Where is Osaka.ttf?

Tags: macos, font, font-book, japanese

I am evaluating some software that needs to use fonts. I need to specify the location of the font. The font I would like it to use is Osaka.

A quick Google search suggests, "Osaka is the default Japanese font included in MacOS" which sounds plausible.

When I specify the location of the fonts as: `/System/Library/Fonts` the software reports that it can't find Osaka there. And indeed, the file is not there! Nor is it in `/Library/Fonts`... and neither is it in `~/Library/Fonts`. And a Finder search comes up dry. But in Font Book, I can find Osaka there with the collection of "System Fonts".

[image: Screenshot of the Font Book window showing a font named Osaka with the contextual menu and the 'Show in Finder' greyed out]

You can see that the "Show in Finder" command is greyed out. So the question is, **How can I refer to this Osaka font as a file?** Can I extract it from somewhere?

I'm uncomfortable downloading it as the downloaded definition could clash with the built-in font.

The system is macOS Ventura 13.6

Screenshot in response to request for clarifying information:
[image]

Comment: Aren't there any other Japanese fonts at the bottom of the list when you navigate to `/System/Library/Fonts/` ?

Comment: Is the font currently installed and shown in font selection panels? I can't find it either; but I haven't installed it. (It's optional, so probably not the default Japanese font.) Is the filepath not shown under "Details" in the right-hand panel? However, I'm curious what this app is that you need a filepath to "use" a font.

Comment: @tama yes, there are a number of "hiragan-" fonts. They are all represented as files, as expected.

Comment: @benwiggy the app is Iceni Infix Server trial edition. The file path is not shown in "details". I added a second screenshot. As for your first question, I don't know how to answer it. What is a font selection panel exactly?

Comment: A Font Selection Panel is the dialog where you choose a font to use for your text. Command T in Pages or TextEdit. Other apps might have a drop-down menu list of fonts. "Can you style text in Osaka in a text app?" is what I'm asking.

Comment: So, I learned a few things in the process of resolving this. Osaka is no longer a default font released with MacOS and it may even be abandonware. Apple licensed some fonts called Hiragino and these are found as files in /System/Library/Fonts. I was mis-reading the kana when I called these "Hiragan" above. The closest visual match to Osaka is Hiragino "Maru" (rounded) but I still like Osaka better. Google is promoting Noto Sans Japanese which also has OK looking glyphs. The licensing however... is an exercise for the implementor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `/System/Library/AssetsV2/`

```
cd /System/Library/AssetsV2/; find . -iname '*osaka*'
```

This outputs for me:

```
./com_apple_MobileAsset_Font7/0818d874bf1d0e24a1fe62e79f407717792c5ee1.asset/AssetData/OsakaMono.ttf
./com_apple_MobileAsset_Font7/a3f9a9e35bdf3babe03b2fd162051306fad439d6.asset/AssetData/Osaka.ttf
./PreinstalledAssetsV2/InstallWithOs/com_apple_MobileAsset_Font6/6e5a0f19f3737bb24d3fd26f5232d3c22f13d772.asset/AssetData/OsakaMono.ttf
./PreinstalledAssetsV2/InstallWithOs/com_apple_MobileAsset_Font6/c5bb7e8e17b14e3d0cfa9f59af77b7d3acebb045.asset/AssetData/Osaka.ttf
```

This other Apple Stackexchange post helped me find this directory: [Where are my Fonts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415020/where-are-my-fonts)

Comment: Your answer... it's like magic! I can see in my install history, this Mac has been upgraded to Catalina then Monterey and then Ventura. Maybe I downloaded the font years ago or maybe it is a prior default and now moved to optional.

Regardless, I can think of no good reason that /System/Library/AssetsV2 is excluded from the Spotlight index!